# Why does my IDE suggest to rewrite != 0 to is not 0

Tags: python, pycharm

My python IDE PyCharm by defaults suggests to change the following line of python:

```
if variable != 0:
```

to

```
if variable is not 0:
```

Why does it suggest this? Does it matter at all for the execution (i.e. does this behave different for any edge cases)?

Comment: May be interesting to see if it happens for other ints or just `0`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a bug. You should not test integers by identity. Although it may work ok for small integers, it's just an implementation detail.

If you were checking `variable is False`, that would be ok. Perhaps the IDE is tripped up by the semantics

Comment: Is there a reason why you should not? I'd be interested to know.

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim, on the version of Python I have here, `100 is 99+1` evaluates to `True`, but `1000 is 999+1` evaluates to `False`. Instances of `int` have ids just like any other object. In CPython, small integers are preallocated as an optimisation, only `those` integers will work with `is` and it's not guaranteed for other implementations of Python

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim this explains it a little further: http://docs.python.org/c-api/int.html#PyInt_FromLong

Comment: "If you were checking variable is False, that would be ok" : not even. Quite a few objects test false in a boolean context without being the False object.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers, that's not the point being made. Any time the bool value `False` occurs it is guaranteed to be the same object. This is different from "falsey" values

Answer (score 1):

`is not` should be preferred if your matching object's identity not equality.
see these examples

```
>>> a=[1,2,3]
>>> b=[1,2,3]  #both are eqaul
>>> if a is not b:
     print('they are eqaul but they are not the same object')    

they are eqaul but they are not the same object

>>> if a != b:
     print('hello') #prints nothing because both have same value

>>> a=100000
>>> b=100000
>>> a is b
False
>>> if a is not b:
    print('they are eqaul but they are not the same object')


they are eqaul but they are not the same object
>>> if  a!=b:
    print('something') #prints nothing as != matches their value not identity
```

But if the numbers stored in a and b are small integers or small strings then `a is not b` will not work as python does some **caching**, and they both point to the same object.

```
>>> a=2
>>> b=2
>>> a is b
True
>>> a='wow'
>>> b='wow'
>>> a is b
True
>>> a=9999999
>>> b=9999999
>>> a is b
False
```

Comment: I'm not sure that's the case. For a boolean check, it would be better to say `if variable:`.

Comment: No it's not.  It's more Pythonic to use `is`/`is not` when checking for `None`, but not for zero.

Answer (score 1):

The != operator checks for non equality of value. The `is` operator is used to check for identity. In Python, you cannot have two instances of the same integer literal so the expressions have the same effect. The `is not 0` reads more like English which is probably why the IDE is suggesting it (although I wouldn't accept the recommendation).

I did try some analysis. I dumped the bytecode for both the expressions and can't see any difference in the opcodes. One has `COMPARE_OP               3 (!=)` and the other has `COMPARE_OP               9 (is not)`. They're the same. I then tried some performance runs and found that time taken is negligibly higher for the `!=`.

Comment: in python you can have two instances of the same integer, so the expressions do not necessarily have the same effect, you're mistaken. Try out `300+1 is 301`.

Comment: Yup. I got that after gnibblers answer above.

Answer (score 0):

The operator "is not" is checking for object identity and the operator != checks for object equality. I do not think there you should do this in your case but maybe your ide suggests this for the general case?